# What does the phrase 'she may bear on my knees' mean in Genesis 30:3?

Tags: genesis, jacob, nasb

Genesis 30:3 NASB

3 She said, “Here is my maid Bilhah, go in to her that ***she may bear on my knees***, that [b]through her I too may have children.”

What does this phrase mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "bear upon the knees" is a very Hebrew piece of idiom surrounding the birthing custom of the time.  When  a child was born, it was placed, usually on the knees (in modern terms we say "lap") of the father and mother.

Thus, Rachel was essentially saying that any children born to Bilhah would be placed upon Rachel's knees, thus signifying that Rachel, not Bilhah, would be recognized as the mother, according to the custom of the time.

Ellicott says the same thing:

> She shall bear upon my knees.—So in Genesis 1:23, it is said, in the
> Hebrew, that “the children of Machir were born upon Joseph’s knees,”
> not borne, as in our margin. It appears that there was a custom of
> placing the new-born child upon the knees, first of the father, who,
> by accepting it. acknowledged the infant as his own; and secondly,
> upon those of the mother. In this case, as Bilhah’s children were
> regarded as legally born of Rachel, they would be placed upon Rachel’s
> knees. Probably, too, the children of Machir, by being placed upon
> Joseph’s knees, were in some way adopted by him.

The Cambridge commentary is more helpful again:

> bear upon my knees] By this phrase Rachel means that she will
> recognize and adopt as her own the children by her handmaid, Bilhah.
> For the phrase, cf. Genesis 50:23; Job 3:12. The child being received
> on the knees of the parent was regarded as being accepted into the
> family. The words retain the trace of a primitive ceremony of
> legitimatization and adoption.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a reference to the process of adoption at birth.

When a child is born, the doctor or midwife places the child on the chest or lap of the mother to allow the child to get acquainted with mother.

In this Bible passage, it is likely that, the person who will adopt the child as his or her own is also in the birthing room to receive the child on her chest or lap, and even on the father's chest if the adopting mother is not present.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned from somewhere that "bear upon my knees" refers to an even stranger custom where the servant would sit on the lap of the mistress while giving birth and the baby would, thus, pass through the legs of the mistress, acknowledging her as the rightful mother.

Comment: Thank you for considering this question. However, it is most beneficial when references are given to substantiate the Answer.  Otherwise the answer is just hearsay, or cultural myth, or tradition. Keep studying the Bible; it brings you closer to Jesus! Blessings.